# Removing not-a-number entries from an array of numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of `{x, y, z}` coordinates from a wavefront sensor I'm working with. However, not all of the imported points have actual values, but they still get imported as `{x, y, "NaN"}`. I'm trying to find a way to get rid of these faulty points, but so far, I can't find a way to identify them. They don't affect some graphs, but I've run into trouble when performing operations on the set of points

I've tried several things like `Delete`, `DeleteCases` and `StringTrim`, but to no avail.

When I run, `DeleteCases[graph, "NaN"]`, for example, I get back the same set of points.

Also, I am using *Mathematica* 7.

Thanks.

Comment: On one of the erroneous data points, would run `FullForm` and post the result?

Comment: I have never seen Mathematica Imports return NaN. This must be a remnant of another program. Anyway, `DeleteCases` should be able to get rid of them. Please provide the code you tried,  otherwise we can't comment  on what you did wrong.

Comment: Here is the FullForm for one point:{-1.35714, -1.21429, 0.25 (-0.699 + "       NaN")}

So far I have tried Delete and DeleteCases, I am new to Mathematica, so I have not explored much else. Thank for your help.

Comment: Try `Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, {-1.35714, -1.21429, 
   0.25 (-0.699 + " NaN")}}, {_, _, _?NumberQ}]` or `DeleteCases[{{1, 2, 3}, {-1.35714, -1.21429, 
   0.25 (-0.699 + " NaN")}}, {_, _, _?(Not[NumberQ[#]] &)}]`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much. I will have to familiarize myself with this notation further.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries please post that as an answer

Comment: Looks like you have an extra space in the " NaN" have you tried adding the space to your DeleteCases?

Answer (score 4):

According to comments, some data points are imported as:

```
{-1.35714, -1.21429, 0.25 (-0.699 + "NaN")}
```

where the + indicates that some preprocessing has already been carried out. Per Sjoerd's comment the solutions is to filter cases where each value of a triplet is a valid number:

```
Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, {-1.35714, -1.21429, 0.25 (-0.699 + " NaN")}}, {_, _, _?NumberQ}]
```

or remove cases where the triplet's last entry is not a number:

```
DeleteCases[{{1, 2, 3}, {-1.35714, -1.21429, 0.25 (-0.699 + " NaN")}},
            {_, _, _?(Not[NumberQ[#]] &)}]
```

Comment: You might want to replace `NumberQ` with `NumericQ`, since `NumberQ` returns false for symbolic numbers, such as `Pi`.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand your question correctly. Try this :

```
x = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, "NaN"}, {6, 7, 7 + 1}}
isOk[u_] := NumberQ[u[[1]]] && NumberQ[u[[2]]] && NumberQ[u[[3]]];
Select[x, isOk[#] &]
```

output :

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {6, 7, 8}}
```

Or even, for higher dimensions :

```
isOk[u_] := And @@ NumberQ /@u
```

or (slower but uses less advanced syntax)

```
isOk[u_] := NumberQ[Total[u]];
```