# Max of imported numerical data will not work

Tags: list-manipulation, import, maximum

I loaded a list with 400,000 values from a file. The list was loaded correctly as I can get it's length (by Length[]) and I can also plot it.

Why can't I get the Max or Min of this list though? When I try to evaluate the cell, I simply get "Max[all the values of my list]" as output.

My file contains a list of floats, each on its own line, separated by a newline.

I load them like this:

```
list = ReadList["myfile.txt"]
```

Mathematica converts some of the floats into a weird "integer + float e" format, for example "9 + 1.4443 e". Thus, not all values are numerical but I still need to take them into account.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of your list (eg. `myList[[ 1 ;; 10 ]]`  or by using `Short`) ?

Comment: @gwr {0.26304, -0.0398959, -0.330003, -0.565977, -0.734065, -0.813924, \
-0.796839, -0.702942, -0.544771, -0.345005}

Comment: I copied and pasted your list but I notice that there is a '\' before the 7th element. Could this be what is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing not-a-number entries from an array of numbers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27636/removing-not-a-number-entries-from-an-array-of-numbers)

Comment: What does `CountsBy[myList, NumericQ]` return? Where $\text{myList}$ is the variable name holding your list.

Comment: @JohnConorCosnett No, the backslash must have been a copy+paste bug.

Comment: @gwr {{Real, 384431}, {Plus, 11078}, {Integer, 9}} - The pluses are added by mathematica though. I can't give more code because I don't have more code. Just a command to import my file, and the file itself.

Comment: @Edmund <|True -> 384440, False -> 11078|>, where all false occurences are pluses added by mathematica while importing

Comment: @garej Not a duplicate. See my edited post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Proper Input of file and checking the list

Make sure that the variable `list` does contain your file inputs and make sure that *Mathematica* correctly understands your numbers. For this you might try:

```
list = SemanticImport[ "myfile.txt", "Number", "List" ]
```

or using `ReadList` you might try:

```
list = ReadList[ "myfile.txt", "Number" ]
```

Then check whether there still is anything besides numeric quantities:

```
list // Map[ NumericQ] // Apply[And]
```

If everything is ok, then you should see `True` as a result.

To further ponder the `Plus` problem you should check for what exactly happens by looking at the result of:

```
Select[ list, Head[#] == Plus & ][[1]] // FullForm
```

As we have discussed in the comments here, you probably have read in some number like "10e+3" which causes problems if not addressed by giving the type as in above uses of `SemanticImport` or `ReadList`.

### Finding the Max and Min anyway

If your result was `False` you may get some result anyway but simply just selecting the numeric elements:

```
list // RightComposition[
    Select[NumericQ], 
    Through[{Max, Min}[#]] &
  ]
```

### Fixing the Plus expressions returned for floats

To address the problem of `Plus` given for exponential numbers you may also try:

```
list = list /. Plus[ exp_ , Times[ coef_, e ] ] :> coef \[Times] 10.^exp
```

That should take care of the false representation using `ReadList` without giving the type "Number".

Comment: Returns false since Mathematica transforms my float numbers into something like "integer + float", thus making the list contain pluses. Your function seems awesome, but unfortunately the results will be a little off since the "transformed" floats won't be taking into account. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Thanks, this solved everything!

Comment: Fyi, `SemanticImport` is not currently reliable for many variable data types, eg dates and times.

Answer (score 3):

I am only a beginner at *Mathematica* but I notice that `Max` is left unevaluated if given non numerical data types:

[image]

I recommend sampling your data:

```
RandomSample[lista,10}
```

and applying the `Head[]` function to a few elements which returns the data type

Comment: My list only contains numerical types, though?

Comment: @GandalfSchmidt : Your *file* contains numerical types.  You haven't provided any examples of what your list contains that isn't a simple number.